# How to assign to readonly route params in angular 4?

Tags: angular

One of the route params in my angular 4 project has a slash in it so I encoded that route url, but when the actual page is getting loaded then I need to decode that route param again back to normal which is not allowing and raising "Cannot assign to readonly propery 'param1' of object"

Ex:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(encodeURI('route1/' + param1.replace(/\#/g, ':').replace(/\//g, '\u2215'))
```

Here I am trying to decode param1 to its normal by using the below code in route1 page:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
params.param1 = decodeURI(params).readme.replace(/\u2215/g, '/');
})
```

which is raising the error as "Cannot assign to readonly propery 'param1' of object". Could you let me know how to get the actual param.

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to assign to `params` object (`params.param1` must be a `const`, so you cannot assign to it again). Create new objects to keep track of the changed parameters.

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
var param1 = decodeURI(params).readme.replace(/\u2215/g, '/');
//use param 1 here
})
```